# Problems at postgresql full text search with words, containing single quotes

Tags: php, postgresql

I need to use a full text search to get the rows where the column contains the word  `O'henry`

My code:

```
$word = "O'henry";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE to_tsvector('english', col) @@ to_tsquery(:word) ";

$sth = $db->prepare( $sql );
$sth->execute(
    array(":word"=>$word)
);
```

I have two problems:

1) This query matches columns which contains the word `O'henry`, but it also matches columns containing, for example: "O yes, thierry henry is good sportsman."

2) If `$word` begins with quotes, for example `'henry`, I got an error: `syntax error in tsquery: "'henry"`, in spite of the fact that the search string was already escaped.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using ph_escape_string?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php.

Comment: Thanks very much, this solves 2 problem (in my question), but 1) problem still stays .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default english dictionary is going to tokenize your data treating the `'` as a it would a space. You can use `ts_debug` to inspect how PostgreSQL/tsearch will treat your text:

```
psql=# SELECT * FROM ts_debug('english','o''henry');
   alias   |   description   | token |  dictionaries  |  dictionary  | lexemes 
-----------+-----------------+-------+----------------+--------------+---------
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | o     | {english_stem} | english_stem | {o}
 blank     | Space symbols   | '     | {}             |              | 
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | henry | {english_stem} | english_stem | {henri}
(3 rows)
```

It's clear from this output that if you want to have postgres treat `o'henry` as a single word, you are going to have to either:

- create a custom dictionary to handle words with apostrophes
- *or* strip apostrophes from both your `tsvector` and `tsquery` before use.

I'd say the second option is by far the easiest:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE plainto_tsvector('english', replace(col, '''','')) @@ to_tsquery(replace(:word,'''',''));"
```

Comment: Do you know how to create a custom dictionary for it? I already have a custom one for removing accents so it'd be nice to bake this into it as well.

Answer (score 3):

After reading through the documentation, I believe that this is a limitation within the types of strings accepted by `to_tsquery`. According to [this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/textsearch-controls.html):

> the input to to_tsquery must already follow the general rules for
>   tsquery input

The tsquery input rules are defined [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-textsearch.html). Based on the examples given, the engine processes each input word into single-quoted strings, which will break on your input. As a workaround, I found a suggestion in [this forum post](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20080806221849.GA3676@alvh.no-ip.org) (where the user was trying to properly escape the input `'ksan`:

```
select *
from items
where to_tsvector(name) @@ to_tsquery(E'[\']ksan')
```

To apply this to your situation, you would need to pre-format your input using something like this:

```
$word = 'E' . str_replace("'", "[\']", $word);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this solves 2 problem (in my question), but 1) problem still stays

Comment: Have you verified this by testing? As I understand it, the first problem is caused because your search term is being split into two strings ('O' and 'henry'), and this new method should prevent that.

Comment: Yes, tested, this query: `... WHERE to_tsvector('english', col) @@ to_tsquery(E'O[\']henry')` matches also that columns, which  contains text: `O some words here henry`

Comment: Hm, I see. I will continue looking for a solution, but based on open question such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997943/postgresql-fulltext-search-for-words-with-apostrophes), I am not overly hopeful.